# PHP SQL - left join + where + or

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I'm improving my search bars in a project's back-office.
I want to make a research in the `protfolio` **table**, joining the `category`**table** to include the *category's names* in the available **keywords**. Seems simple, but the only message I'll get is :

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'search_0' in 'where clause' in [...]

I am creating the SQL query dynamically before executing it, like this :

```
$keywords = explode(" ", $_POST['search']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio LEFT JOIN category
          ON portfolio.portfolio_category_id = category.category_id
          WHERE ";

$query_array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i += 1) {
    $query .= "portfolio.portfolio_title LIKE :search_" . $i;
    $query .= " OR category.category_name LIKE search_" . $i;

    if ($i != (count($keywords) - 1)) {
        $query .= " OR ";
    }
    $query_array['search_' . $i] = "%" . $keywords[$i] . "%";
}

$list_portf = $bdd->prepare($query);
$list_portf->execute($query_array);
```

I'm not a crack in SQL I don't really understand where is the error (I didn't find an answer in the question I found). Thanks.

Comment: Can you `echo $query_array` before executing query? That should help us find error

Comment: @KuKeC I missed a colon (the answer I got where right). Sorry !
I'm closing the question

Comment: I feel I must note that the search term from the user should never be inserted directly into a SQL query without filtering.  This is the definition of a SQL injection vulnerability.  Perhaps see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @pseudocoder my query is prepared before executing.
First the query is created in the string `$query` while the keywords are put into an array `$query_array`. Then the 2 variables are sent to the methods `->prepare()` and `->execute()` (at the end).
I don't see where am I vulnerable to SQL injections ?

Comment: @AymDev maybe I'm missing something, but it appears you are inserting values from the user (`$_POST['search']`) directly into the query.  That is the key characteristic of an injection vulnerability, since the user values could be anything, including statement terminations followed by additional statements such as DML, updates/inserts/deletes, etc.

Comment: @pseudocoder [pdo::prepare - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) - [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Please tell me how should I proceed because I really don't understand where does this fail. Or maybe you read something wrong ? I hope so, I don't want to rewrite a complete project :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you missed  colon `:` before your second ref to search_

```
   " OR category.category_name LIKE :search_" . $i;
```

Comment: Okay I'm closing the question. Really sorry !

Comment: @AymDev  nothing  to sorry ..everyone do mistake ... well  if my answer is right just mark it as accepted ..

Comment: I apparently can't before 6 min (but I'll do).
But my question won't help anybody, I flagged it myself as I can't delete it.

Comment: A question is a question  .. It 'hard to say if it can be useful or not. often the syntax errors are time expensive. .. And finding a solution is a nice convenience